# Rails (agile web development with rails 4th edition) After creating a Cart, can not find a file named current_cart.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to follow an example which named "Finding a Cart" and here is my code

`rails new n
cd n
cd bin
rails generate scaffold Cart
rails db:migrate`

Seems it works very smoothly, in my book, they said that there is a file named `current_cart.rb` at folder `n\app\controllers\concerns` and I must store the ID of the cart in the session by indexing it with the :cart_id symbol, but my problem is, I can not find the file name `current_cart.rb` in that folder. There is only the file named `.keep` ?

Should I make a file named `current_cart.rb` and copy paste the content in that book into that file? Thank you very much for reading my problem.

Comment: You have another edition of the book than I have I guess. Mine just lists the file-name and the contents. Yes: you have to create file.

Answer (score 2):

Anh Bui: I noticed a few points which not looking good to me.

1. Why did you go inside bin(cd bin) and run scaffold that does not require, you can run the same from folder n itself.
2. You ran the scaffold for **Cart** then how you can look for file **current_cart.rb**.
3. In general, concerns file won't create by default you need to create that file inside concerns folder for Model or controller.
4. Create concerns as a **module** concern_name and include that concern in the model or controller where you wants use concern functionality